# wordpress pegar a url do valor do meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Gostaria de pegar as  url separada de value colocado no `meta_key` , tenho um campo personalizado "Custom file" chamado mp3 ai coloco as mp3 múltiplos campos gostaria de pegar url de cada value

esse código abaixo mostra a url apenas da ultima mp3 adicionado:

```
<?php $minha_variavel = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mp3', true); ?>

<?php if ($minha_variavel): ?>
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($minha_variavel); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) recebe um parâmetro booleano chamado *single*, que determina se o retorno da função é um valor único ou um array de valores. No seu caso, você está chamando a função com esse valor como `true`. Experimente deixá-lo como `false`.

Comment: Bom dia ! coloquei como false agora não exibiu nada no caso tenho que colocar o código  dentro de um loop ou nao no caso ele e um campo com múltiplos volumes

Comment: se `$minha_variavel` for um array, vc vai ter que percorre-lo em um laço

Answer (score 1):

Juntando o que os colegas comentaram na sua pergunta o código ficaria assim:

```
$minha_variavel = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mp3'); // O terceiro parâmetro é FALSE por padrão

foreach ($minha_variavel as $arquivo) { // Segundo a documentação o retorno é sempre um array
    echo wp_get_attachment_url($arquivo);
}
```

Comment: Ele esta imprimido as URL dos arquivos porem gostaria de pegar separado exemplo: url do value 2 apenas do segundo arquivo  colocado no meta_key  ha desde ja muito obrigado pela força de vcs